# How to return the value from the stdout?

Tags: go, read-eval-print-loop

I am building a REPL/shell in go for other languages.

I have the following code, and I expect 2 get printed, but nothing got printed.

```
grepCmd := exec.Command("python")
grepIn, _ := grepCmd.StdinPipe()
grepOut, _ := grepCmd.StdoutPipe()
grepCmd.Start()
grepIn.Write([]byte("1+1"))  <- assume this is fixed and we cannot use print().
//grepIn.Write([]byte("print(1+1)")) This one returns 2
grepIn.Close()
grepBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(grepOut)
grepCmd.Wait()
fmt.Println(string(grepBytes)
```

I am not asking how to use `cmd.stdout = os.stdout`.

Comment: Why do you expect `1+1` to write something to stdout? Only `print(1+1)` does it as expected.

Comment: I know that. I am building a REPL/Shell in go. `1 + 1` is the user input. `2` is the output the users expect.

Comment: I guess you can take the user input `1 + 1`, surround it with `print( <input> )` and send it to python process.

Comment: That is not sufficient. Inputs include function/ class etc. Output includes text, json, images, video etc.

Comment: ReadAll reads until the reader is closed, and the StdoutPipe is closed when Wait returns. This is a deadlock. Why don't you want to assign os.Stdout?

Answer (score 1):

When the stdin is connected to a pipe, the python interpreter will run in non-interactive mode by default. So you will get nothing from stdout if you run `echo "1+1" | python` in the shell.

Execute `python -i` to explicitly enable the interactive mode, as in `echo "1+1" | python -i`.